# ansible: accessing last inventory list item/list size within when statement

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I try to check a triple condition within a `when` statement, like this:

```
# Run only on the last of the oct_servers (once all the others have been launched) and only when there are at least 2 servers

when: (container_state == "started" and ansible_host == {{ groups['oct_servers'] | last }} and {{ groups['oct_servers'] | length }} > 1 )
```

But it fails with a warning that {{ }} and {% %} should not be used within a when statement. I left it out, and tried many possible combinations, but without success. What is the correct syntax for the above condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple removing the Jinja delimiters should do:

```yaml
when: container_state == "started" and ansible_host == groups['oct_servers'] | last and groups['oct_servers'] | length > 1
```

Note that `when` conditions needing multiple conditions all being true [can also be expressed as a list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement):

```yaml
when: 
  - container_state == "started"
  - ansible_host == groups['oct_servers'] | last
  - groups['oct_servers'] | length > 1
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this. Even I have reduced it to only the first two conditions, but the condition is not triggered even on the last element. I get `skipping: [10.103.19.63] => {"changed": false, "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"}` for IP is in the list...

Comment: Then `debug:` both `groups['oct_servers']` and `ansible_host` and post those results in your question.

Comment: What I suspect: `ansible_host` is not what you think it is

Comment: You were right, ansible_host was not what I thought it should be. Now it works!